# Cannot login in to my google account on nexus one or acer iconia because of google 2-step verification

Tags: android

I am trying to setup my nexus one and acer iconia google email account and I keep getting "Your username and password do not match". I'm pretty sure it's correct and I strongly suspect it's because of the google 2-step verification:

[google 2-step verification](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1056283&topic=1056284)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your google account settings page. Then click on the edit button next to "Using 2-step verification". Then click on "Manage application-specific passwords". Finally, use the box below things to generate a password.

Comment: As of today, this option appears when you click "Security" in the sidebar of Google's Accounts page.